# Netsuite contact update with an email id as the reference

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite

how do i change the reference to Email in netsuite contact update form. By default it shows first name and last name. how do i change this to email.

> When contact first name and contact last name fields are added to the form, the system will first try to find an existing record for the contact before creating a new record.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SavedSearch` for filtering the email ID and select that record and make changes in it.